# plugin advimage for tinymce 4.x

Tags: tinymce-4

i need vspace, hspace or align for image, than will be found on advimage for tinymce 3.x. 
i was try put advimage plugin on tinymce 4.x but error.

i was try this step

1. I copy advimage folder plugin from tinymcd 3.x into 4.x
2. i was add `"img[!src|border:0|alt|title|width|height|style]a[name|href|target|title|onclick]"` to extended_valid_elements option.

i get from this tutorial :

[advimage-advanced-image-plugin](http://tinymcesupport.com/tutorials/advimage-advanced-image-plugin)

that step is still not working....

Comment: A good article to refer 
>> https://thedevland.com/2018/06/11/what-happened-to-advimage-plugin-in-tinymce/

Comment: [advimage-advanced-image-plugin] link is no longer available

Answer (score 6):

The "advimage" plugin is not available for TinyMCE 4, but you can add an "Advanced" tab on the image dialog box using the `image_advtab` option. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  plugins: ["image", ... others ... ],
  image_advtab: true,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Note the typo in the example: that's `image_advtab`.

Answer (score 1):

ADVIMAGE is not yet supported in version 4.

Look here for the plugins that were dropped:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial%3aMigration_guide_from_3.x)